# Moving Assets among different Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, service, media, assets

In my Azure account we have 7 different media services. Each of them possesses some videos around a thousand. Does any one know how can I move my assets from 6 of media services to only one of them on the cloud. And anyone knows does this move negatively effects the smoothness of streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Media Services is not providing account merging functionality out of a box.

For copying content of your storage account you can utilize AzCopy tool http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx.
This will just move your content to other account without registering assets within a system. You have to write code to re-create your assets within target account and appropriate locators  for streaming.

So if you have azure media services accounts which are heavily used in production, i will recommend you to file a ticket/feature request to azure media services support.

Comment: George, All of the assets are under one account. But they are on different storage and different Media Service instances.

Comment: You mean one subscription? but you have multiple instances with different names,right.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is one subscription. I have 7 instances of media services, 3 one them are linked to one storage instance while the other 4 AMS are linked to another storage instance. And all of them are under one subscription account.

Comment: Unfortunately right now there is no ability to merge assets from multiple media services account  into one account. If it is critical ask for you organization please contact azure customer support to see what can be done from our side to solve your problem.We will have more flexibility in nearest future how you organize asset storage using multiple storage accounts. I will update this thread once we will have official announcement with more details

Comment: Quick update: You can utilize WAMS asset replicator tool for your scenario.

Here is the project link:  https://replicator.codeplex.com/

And this is a helpful blog:
Mariano Converti - http://blogs.southworks.net/mconverti